# How to ETL my PostgreSQL data into a ClickHouse datawarehouse?

Tags: postgresql, etl, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, clickhouse

I have data stored in postgreSQL as data source and I want to load dimensions and fact tables of the clickhouse datawarehouse , I am new to clickhouse and used to use traditional integration tools like Talend and Microsoft SSIS to perform ETL
(PS i'm using docker images for both clickhouse and postgreSQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to import your PostgreSQL data into a new ClickHouse table of the same shape. Let's assume you have a single table named `foo` with two columns, `id` and `foo`.

1. Create a table using the [PostgreSQL Table Engine](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/database-engines/postgresql) to get a view into your pg table (replacing the connection info with your own):

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo_pg
(
    id UUID,
    foo String
) ENGINE = PostgreSQL('host:port', 'database', 'tablename', 'username', 'password');
```

2. Create a new ClickHouse table with the same shape (to avoid type casting on `INSERT`):

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo
(
    id UUID,
    foo String
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
ORDER BY tuple()
PRIMARY KEY(id);
```

3. Use [INSERT INTO](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/insert-into) to import data:

```sql
INSERT INTO foo (id, foo)
SELECT id, foo FROM foo_pg;
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the PostgreSQL engine integration [here](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/postgresql/) where you can perform `SELECT` and `INSERT` queries on ClickHouse on data stored in remote PostgreSQL.

You can also make use of [table function](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/table-functions/postgresql) as well.

Answer (score 2):

You ingest data from Postgres into Clickhouse using:

- External ETL tools like [Airbyte](https://airbyte.com/) and make a connector from Postgres to Clikhouse
- [Clickhouse integrations table engine](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/) to make a view from Clickhouse to Postgres data, after that use `insert into` query to insert data from that view into the real Clickhouse table